# basic xcode iphone app not working, button clicks to change text?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I've followed the tutorial below, it basically just tells you to create a button and a label. When you click the button the label should change to some text.

http://paulpeelen.com/2011/03/17/xcode-4-ios-4-3-hello-world/

It runs but it shows a blank screen. When you click the screen it goes blue like the entire page is a button. I think it's loading the mainwindow.xib file instead of the default ViewController.xib

Any ideas, I'm obviously missing something?

Thanks

EDIT

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface fun_buttonViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *textLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;

- (IBAction)changeTheTextOfTheLabel;

@end
```

The implementation:

```
#import "fun_buttonViewController.h"

@implementation fun_buttonViewController

@synthesize textLabel;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [textLabel release];
}

- (IBAction)changeTheTextOfTheLabel
{
    [textLabel setText:@"Hello, World!"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as I suspected. It's not a code problem, since the code is fine. The tutorial is also perfectly fine. I thought it had to do with the XIB, and when I looked into there this is what I saw:

In your MainWindow.xib, you had a button loading from the ViewController. Why? I don't know. 
It might have been placed there by accident. Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: See the UIButton loading in the ViewController? It was blocking the rest of the view.]
The left view is from your view controller. See the UIButton loading in the ViewController? It is blocking the rest of the view. Just delete the button that's loading OVER your view, and it works perfectly. The view hierarchy, was essentially blocked by that massive extraneous button.

Comment: :)... it's always something simple. I was tearing my hair out in frustration yesterday. Thank you for taking the time to download and look at the source. Brilliant. Thanks you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You probaly made a simple mistake. I would go through the example again and see if you did anything diffrently.

If you post your code or upload your files somewhere I could take a look at it for you.

Its kind of hard to guess what the problem is without seeing what you actually did^^

Comment: Yeah you're probably right.. I've done it twice reading through a book example (Which uses a previous ver of xcode) and the link online.
I'm sure it's something simple, just me being a newbie I'm not sure what to look for.
Thanks for your help, I've added the code above.

Comment: Seems like everything should be working fine at least from what I see. Maybe the tutorial is outdated or something like that. I had success with this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_4_Development_Essentials_Xcode_4_Edition) it covers a lot and all of the examples have been working for me.

Comment: Sum pointed out my mistake, it was a phantom button on the MainWindow.xib overlaying everything. I must of dragged it onto the page at somepoint. Thanks for looking into this for me and validating my code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything from your XIB (most  likely) or  from your app delegate.

Are you sure you connected the buttons properly? 
Send us your code/zip of the project so far.